# express validator invalid email

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express-validator

I'm trying to do a register and login system and I'm using express validator to check the user inputs

here is the code

registerController.js

```
const {validationResult} = require('express-validator');

let getRegisterPage = (req ,res) =>{
    return res.render('register.ejs' , {errors : req.flash("errors")});
    
};

let createNewUser = async (req , res) =>{
        let errorArr = [];
        let validationErrors = validationResult(req);
        if(!validationErrors.isEmpty()){
            let errors = Object.values(validationErrors.mapped());
            errors.forEach((item) =>{
                errorArr.push(item.msg);
            });
            req.flash("errors" , errorArr);
            return res.redirect("/register");
        }   
        console.log(req.body);
};

module.exports = {
    getRegisterPage : getRegisterPage,
    createNewUser : createNewUser

};
```

authValidation.js

```
let {check} = require('express-validator');

let validateRegister = [

check("email" , "Invalid email").isEmpty().trim(),

check("password" , "Invalid password. password must be at least 2 characters long").isLength( {min : 2} ),

check("confirmPassword" , "confirmation password does not match password").custom((value , {req}) =>{
    value == req.body.password;
})
];

module.exports = {
    
    validateRegister : validateRegister

};
```

the problems are :

- I get a flash message : "Invalid email" even though its a correct email
  and when I try not entering any email that flash message does not show up so its kinda doing the opposite here
- second problem is when I enter unmatched password & confirmation password it shows the message "confirmation password does not match password" which is good bu when I try to fix it by entering matched password and confirmation password it either still show me that error message or the app crashes

help me please

Answer (score 1):

You explicitly check for the email to be empty. If it is not, you get an error.
You'd want this instead:
`check("email" , "Invalid email").isEmail()`

It checks if the email field is a valid email and if it is not, throw an error.

Comment: thank you very much that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the

authValidation.js file :

````
let validateRegister = [

check("email" , "Invalid email").isEmail(),

check("password" , "Invalid password. password must be at least 2 characters long").isLength( {min : 2} ),

check("confirmPassword" , "confirmation password does not match password").custom((value , {req}) =>{
   
    return value === req.body.password;
})
];

module.exports = {
    
    validateRegister : validateRegister

};```
````